# Is ながら an adverb?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Looking up into the dictionary I see that ながら is a particle, not familiar with that concept I just know that it connects to verbs and means "while" introducing a new event clause.

But there is lot of similar words to express the same idea : まま、際に、とき、どうじに、加えて which are all adverb types.

Is ながら of the same type? Could you technically use it at the start of a sentence?
If not could you please provide an example of where you use ながら where you can't interchangeably use an adverb from the list above?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. A couple of questions: 1) Which concept are you not familiar with? You're first sentence suggest you know exactly how ながら works. 2) How do you imagine saying something like "I eat while watching TV" using any of まま、際に、とき、どうじに、加えて? 
A clause ending in ながら would certainly be an adverbial clause. Could you edit and clarify your question a little please?

Comment: Of those you listed as adverb types, only 同時に and 加えて could be used at the beginning of a sentence, and neither expresses the same idea as ながら. Syntactically, the former is obviously a noun plus a particle and the latter is a verb form. So I agree with @user3856370. It's not clear what you are really asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should learn more about Japanese grammar and what the basic terms mean.  Japanese sentence construction is very different from English and uses some substantially different concepts, so you cannot just apply English terms directly to all Japanese words without understanding how some of the uniquely Japanese aspects actually work.  If you do not know what "particle" means, which is a fairly basic part of Japanese grammar, then it makes it very difficult to actually answer your question.

The basic answer is: ながら is an *adverbial particle* but it *is still a particle, not an adverb*.  What that means is that it must be connected to something else (in front of it) to be grammatically correct.  You cannot, for example, use it at the beginning of the sentence.

Attaching ながら to the end of another phrase allows *that entire phrase* to function as an adverb in the larger sentence.  However, ながら is arguably not an adverb by itself, because if it is not attached to a larger phrase, it has no actual meaning.  It's just a particle.

If you want to equate it to something in English grammar, the closest approximation would, I think, be that it is similar to a preposition, not an adverb.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing adverb as a part of speech and words/phrases that work adverbially (modifying verb/adjective/adverb).

It is partially a matter of opinion which part of speech a word belongs to, but none of まま、際に、とき、どうじに、加えて is usually considered as an adverb. Neither is ながら, which is the answer to the title.

(According to most dictionaries) ながら (and まま) is a particle, and falls under the subcategory 接続助詞{せつぞくじょし}.

---

As for the others, 際に and どうじに are noun+に; とき is a noun; 加えて is a te-form of verb 加える. (An equivalent of 加えて is the English adverb *additionally*, but that does not make 加えて an adverb.)

All these are not completely interchangeable, but how non-interchangeable is a bit too broad to answer.

Comment: My question was not really about "are the words in the list I provided all adverbs?" because for me they all are, that's just a personal representation. For instance you claim that 加えて is not an adverb because it's made from a verb but adverbs can be made from anything since they express a way of doing thing or is supplement to another verb (that is why if you translate 加えて to English you end up with `additionally`).
Also that is the reason I asked if ながら was considered an adverb or if from a formal point of view it is irrational to use it as an adverb such as 「たべる。ながらTV見てる。」

Comment: What's beautiful about adverbs is that you can use them pretty much freely. But again from a standard point of view you have to respect a certain formalism. If ながら is a grammatical construct I understand that breaking its structure would make a sentence not formally correct.

Comment: @vdegenne When you are using a different/non-standard (/personal?) terminology, you won't be understood unless at least you make that clear. Anyway, ながら can't be used at the beginning as commented.